How do you get file inputs to be recognized across multiple Shiny modules?
I'm trying to make a shiny app that allows the user to upload data on one tab and view reports made from that data on other tabs.
For example, when there is no file uploaded, a message appears asking the user to upload a file. Once it is, that message disappears and a new output appears with their report.
I've successfully done this in the app until I tried to separate each tab into it's own module.
The app uses req() as the conditional function. Once the file is uploaded, it triggers req() and the output appears. I think what might be happening is because of the module structure, the report module isn't recognizing/being triggered by the file upload from the upload data module. It's working on the upload_data module however.
Currently, the message reminding the user to upload their data is not disappearing and the new report output isn't appearing.

I've simplified the code below so it's not as overwhelming, but tried to keep the important factors in so the issue is found
app.R
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  
  tags$div(
    class = "tab-content",
    
    ## Upload Data UI ----------------------------------------------------------
    tags$div(
      class = "tab-pane active",
      id = "data_upload",
      upload_data_UI("data_upload")
    ),
    
    ## Reports UI ---------------------------------------------------
    tags$div(
      class = "tab-pane",
      id = "gen_supervisor_reports",
      supervisor_UI("gen_supervisor_reports")
    )
  )
)

# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  upload_data_Server("data_upload")
  supervisor_Server("gen_supervisor_reports")
}

# Run App -----------------------------------------------------------------
shinyApp(ui, server)

upload_data_logic.R
upload_data_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(tags$div(class = "container-fluid", div(
    class = "row text-center",
    div(
      class = "col-xl-12",
      br(), br(), br(), br(), br(),
      
      fluidRow(
        column(width = 3),
        column(
          width = 3,
          align = "center",
          h2("Upload Your Data"),
          p("Upload files here to generate reports on other tabs."),
          br(),
          
          fileInput(
            ns("files"),
            label = "Clock-In Data",
            multiple = TRUE,
            accept = c(
              "text/csv",
              "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
              ".csv"
            )
          )
        ),
        
        column(
          width = 3,
          align = "center",
          h2("Available Reports:"),
          br(),
          uiOutput(ns("sup_report_live"))
        ),
        column(width = 3)
      )
    )
  )))
}

upload_data_Server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    
    output$sup_report_live <- renderUI({
      req(input$files)
      
      column(
        width = 12,
        align = "center",
        tags$a(
          onclick = "$('a[href=\"#gen_supervisor_reports\"]').tab('show');",
          "Supervisor Reports",
          class = "btn btn-primary"
        )
      )
    })
  })
}

supervisor_report_logic.R
supervisor_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(tags$div(
    class = "tab-pane",
    id = "gen_supervisor_reports",
    tags$div(class = "container-fluid", div(
      class = "row text-center",
      div(
        class = "col-xl-12",
        br(), br(),
        
        column(
          width = 12,
          align = "center",
          uiOutput(ns("sup_dat_needed")),
          
          div(
            class = "row",
            column(width = 3),
            column(width = 6, br(), br(), uiOutput(ns(
              "supervisor_options"
            )), br(), uiOutput(ns(
              "supervisor_download_but"
            )), br()),
            column(width = 3)
          )
        )
      )
    ))
  ))
}

supervisor_Server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    
    output$sup_dat_needed <- renderUI({
      if (is.null(input$files)) {
        column(
          width = 12,
          align = "center",
          h3("Data Needed:"),
          p("Clock-In"),
          br(),
          tags$a(onclick = "$('a[href=\"#data_upload\"]').tab('show');", "Upload Data", class = "btn btn-primary")
        )
      } else {
        NULL
      }
    })
    
    output$supervisor_options <- renderUI({
      req(input$files)
      
      tagList(div(
        align = "center",
        class = "box-container",
        
        h3("Options"),
        hr(class = "hr-blue"),
        selectizeInput(
          "reports_supervisor",
          label = "Site",
          choices = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", ),
          selected = "ABC",
          options = list(create = TRUE)
        ),
        br()
      ))
    })
    
    output$supervisor_download_but <- renderUI({
      req(input$files)
      
      tagList(
        br(),
        h3("Download"),
        hr(class = "hr-blue"),
        downloadButton(ns("DownloadSupervisorReport"))
      )
    })
  })
}


I hope I've provided enough info, and thank you so much in advance to anyone who goes through this to help me!

This question is similar to: How to update shiny module with reactive dataframe from another module. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You need to make your upload module return a reactive, which you then monitor in your main server and pass to your report module.
